# SpringBoot @PreAuthorize with String.contains or regex in hasAuthority

Tags: spring-boot, authorization

I am using Spring Boot (2.7.6) and I am looking at `@PreAuthorize` annotation.

I am wondering how can I use `String.Contains` or `regex` matching to check for valid authorities within `hasAuthority` method.

For example, I have following authorities:

```
MYAPI_ORDER_PROCESSING_DEV
MYAPI_ORDER_PROCESSING_PROD
MYAPI_ORDER_TRACKING_DEV
MYAPI_ORDER_TRACKING_PROD
```

In some cases, I might just need `MYAPI_ORDER_PROCESSING_DEV` in which case, I can use

```java
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('MYAPI_ORDER_PROCESSING_DEV')
```

In other cases, I can check for any of number of authorities like:

```java
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority(
   'MYAPI_ORDER_PROCESSING_DEV', 
   'MYAPI_ORDER_PROCESSING_PROD', 
   'MYAPI_ORDER_TRACKING_DEV', 
   'MYAPI_ORDER_TRACKING_PROD')
```

This is all clear and working for me, but this might get to long and complicated if I have a long list of authorities.

I wonder if there is a way to use `String.contains(substring)` or `regex` to match multiple authorities.  For example, something like:

```java
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority(authorityString.Contains('MYAPI_ORDER_')
```

, which would match all 4 authorities above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a component that handles the logic for checking authorities:

```java
@Component
public class AuthorityHelper {

  public boolean hasAuthorityContaining(Authentication authentication, String substring) {
    return authentication.getAuthorities().stream()
        .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
        .anyMatch(i -> i.contains(substring));
  }
}
```

Since `@PreAuthorize` supports SpEL expressions, it can be defined as follows:

```java
@PreAuthorize("@authorityHelper.hasAuthorityContaining(authentication, 'MYAPI_ORDER_')")
```

`authentication` is a built-in `Authentication` instance associated with the method invocation and it contains authorities among other data.

Reference:  [Spring Documentation - Expressing Authorization with SpEL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/method-security.html#authorization-expressions)

Comment: Much appreciated.  That is a great explanation